# How to use a globally defined nullable variable as not null in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

When writing an implementation in kotlin, I would like to use globally defined variables as non-null. Functionally these variables cannot be null, but technical implementation requires them to be nullable.

The solution I use so far is:

```kotlin
val funtionalValue = if (global.technicalValue != null) global.technicalValue!! else throw someException()
```

Is there a way to assign the `functionalValue` without using `!!` on the globally defined technical value?

Comment: If you don't care about the type and message of exception thrown, `!!` should be okay. It throws a `NullPointerException`

Comment: just wondering, why don't you want to use `!!`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are standard-library functions you might want to use, called  `checkNotNull` and `requireNotNull`.

```
val funtionalValue = checkNotNull(global.technicalValue)
```

This will result in an `IllegalStateException` being thrown, in case the value is null. `requireNotNull` will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` and is better suited to validate function parameters and user input.

If you want to control the exception that is thrown, instead of `if` and `!!` you could also use the elvis operator.

```
val funtionalValue = global.technicalValue ?: throw someException
```

---

Thanks @Sweeper for pointing out `checkNotNull`.

Comment: `checkNotNull` might be better for a global value since it throws an `IllegalStateException`. `requireNotNull` throws an `IllegalArgumentException` which might not be suitable for a global value.

Comment: @Sweeper That's right.